# How do i get the latest checked value of the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code that would get the value of the checkbox, but not the one that is checked the latest, it get the last(?) value of the checkbox. I would like to get the value of the checkbox that is recently checked.

This is my html.

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    class="custom-control-input chkbx"
    value="123456"
    data-valuetwo="Mike"
    id="customCheck32"
    name="choice[]"
  />
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck32">Mike</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    class="custom-control-input chkbx"
    value="6542321"
    data-valuetwo="John"
    id="customCheck33"
    name="choice[]"
  />
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck33">John</label>
</div>

<div id="selecteditems" style="border: 1px solid black"></div>

<div class="itemhead"></div>
```

This is my script.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(".chkbx").click(function() {
    var selected = "";
    var latestchoice = "";
    $(".chkbx:checked").each(function() {
      selected += $(this).attr("data-valuetwo") + "<br>";
      latestchoice = $(this).attr("data-valuetwo");
    });
    $("#selecteditems").html(selected);

    if ($(".itemhead").is(":empty")) {
      $(".itemhead").html(latestchoice);
    } else {
      $(".itemhead").empty();
      $(".itemhead").html(latestchoice);
    }
  });
</script>
```

With the following code, if I check Mike first, then John, I could see the latest choice changing from Mike to John. However, if I selected John first and select Mike, the value of latest choice would not change to Mike. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, one question, what if you check checkbox1 and then checkbox2 and then uncheck checkbox2, what would you like to be your result?

Comment: I would like my result to be checkbox1

Comment: Ok. First, put event as argument of your click function. So you can check in the target which checkbox was clicked and was it checked or unchecked. 
https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Second, you need to store state in an array. 
So, your function should check if the checkbox is checked then add the name to the array if the checkbox is unchecked then remove it from the array. And you should display the last element of that array (if it has elements).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do that, you'll have to remember *when* the checkboxes were checked. One way to do that is to use jQuery's data cache for elements, see comments:

```
$(".chkbx").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  // If this checkbox is checked...
  if (this.checked) {
    // ...remember when
    $this.data("checked", Date.now());
  } else {
    // Not checked, remove the data
    $this.removeData("checked");
  }
  var selected = "";
  var latestchoice = "";
  // Get and sort the checked checkboxes
  var checked = $(".chkbx:checked").get().sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).data("checked") - $(b).data("checked");
  });
  // Loop through them in sorted order
  checked.forEach(function(cb) {
    var $cb = $(cb);
    selected += $cb.attr("data-valuetwo") + "<br>";
    latestchoice = $cb.attr("data-valuetwo");
  });
  $("#selecteditems").html(selected);

  if ($(".itemhead").is(":empty")) {
    $(".itemhead").html(latestchoice);
  } else {
    $(".itemhead").empty();
    $(".itemhead").html(latestchoice);
  }
});
```

Live Example:

```js
$(".chkbx").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  // If this checkbox is checked...
  if (this.checked) {
    // ...remember when
    $this.data("checked", Date.now());
  } else {
    // Not checked, remove the data
    $this.removeData("checked");
  }
  var selected = "";
  var latestchoice = "";
  // Get and sort the checked checkboxes
  var checked = $(".chkbx:checked").get().sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).data("checked") - $(b).data("checked");
  });
  // Loop through them in sorted order
  checked.forEach(function(cb) {
    var $cb = $(cb);
    selected += $cb.attr("data-valuetwo") + "<br>";
    latestchoice = $cb.attr("data-valuetwo");
  });
  $("#selecteditems").html(selected);

  if ($(".itemhead").is(":empty")) {
    $(".itemhead").html(latestchoice);
  } else {
    $(".itemhead").empty();
    $(".itemhead").html(latestchoice);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    class="custom-control-input chkbx"
    value="123456"
    data-valuetwo="Mike"
    id="customCheck32"
    name="choice[]"
  />
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck32">Mike</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    class="custom-control-input chkbx"
    value="6542321"
    data-valuetwo="John"
    id="customCheck33"
    name="choice[]"
  />
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck33">John</label>
</div>

<div id="selecteditems" style="border: 1px solid black"></div>

<div class="itemhead"></div>
This is my script.

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That said, a list you can drag items around in might make for a better UX.